# Single quotes in a variable name in Perl?

Tags: perl, single-quotes, variable-names

I was writing some Perl code in vim and accidentally typed a single quote character in a variable name and noticed that it highlighted it in a different color than normal single quoted strings.

[image]

I thought that was odd, so I wrote a small test program (shown above) and tried to run it to see how Perl would handle it and I got this error:

`"my" variable $var::with::apostrophes can't be in a package`

What exactly is going on here? Are there situations where single quotes in variable names are actually valid? If so, what  meaning do single quotes have when used in this context?

Comment: That's how Damian writes things like [Acme::Don't](https://metacpan.org/pod/Acme::Don::t) :-)

Comment: Why is this a thing...? I especially love the section on **Bugs**: "Unlikely, since it doesn't actually do anything. However, bug reports and other feedback are most welcome." LOL

Comment: In case it's not clear, anything in the Acme namespace should not be taken seriously.

Comment: Although I actually kind of wish this worked in combination with `unless`. It would be pretty cool to be able to write `don't die unless $error;` haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The single quote is the namespace separator used in Perl 4, replaced by the double colon `::` in Perl 5. Because Perl is *mostly* backwards compatible, this still works. It's [great for golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95999/4720), but not much else.

[Here's an article](https://www.perl.com/article/obscure-perl-trick-single-quote-separators/) about it on perl.com that doesn't explain it.

Comment: I can't find any documentation for it online. Maybe I don't have good Google Fu today. I'm sure I've read this in a book at some point.

Comment: See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#The-Syntax-of-Variable-Names

Comment: That's a good find @clamp, but it also doesn't explain _why_ this exists.